# vue ref on custom child component not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I've been googling for hours, reading countless *vue* docs and relevant posts on stackoverflow without luck.

I need to access an internal property of a component, because that component is nothing but a wrapper for a vanilla component which I need access to in the parent.

I am trying to create a ref which is unique and accessible only inside the parent (`App`) component, and my understanding is that I should do that inside `setup` method like so: `const myRef = ref(null)`

But alas, `myRef.value` is forever `null`

#### [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/tagify-tags-component-vue-example-forked-1spu6?file=/src/App.vue)

### Entry file:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from "./App.vue";

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

### Parent `App.vue`:

```js
<template>
    <Foo ref="myRef"/>
</template>

<script>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
import Foo from "./components/Foo.vue"

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: { Foo },

  setup(props) {
    const myRef = ref(null)

    onMounted(()=>{
      console.log(111,  myRef.value)
    })

    return {
      myRef
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

### Child component `Foo.vue`:

```js
<template>
  <div>xxx</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Foo",
  mounted() {
    this.test = 123
  }
}
</script>
```

if I place `ref="myRef"` on the `<h1>` it works, but I need it to work on my *custom component* so I could access things there...

Now I don't know jack**** about *vue*, and there's a TON of very conflicting confusing information out there.. I am using version `v3` in my demo and the `App` component is authored in that manner (from what little I could understand from the insanity out there) but my component `tagify.vue` is authored in `v2` fashion - for wider audience usage.

---

## UPDATE - after lots of wasted hours

it's ***codesandbox console* bug**! it's wrongly displaying it as `null`
I trusted their console too much not to open the browser's one (due to performance reasons as it greatly slows my computer on that specific website).

Comment: It should be `this.$refs.myRef` instead (at least in Vue.js 2.x). Mixing Vue.js 2.x and 3.x isn’t a great idea IMHO.

Comment: @FedericoMoretti - consider `tags` a vue2 compoent imported from `npm`. it's a perfectly normal scenario. Note that there is no such thing as `this` in the parent's code. It's vue3 new API

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue and resolved it on Vue Discord server. This is how you do it in Vue 3, with composition API:

App.vue:

```html
<template>
  <v-header @get-started="scrollToTable" />
  <v-table ref="tableRef" />
</template>

<script setup>
import VTable from "./components/Table.vue";

import { ref } from "vue";

const tableRef = ref(null);

const scrollToTable = () => {
  tableRef.value.getRef()?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
};
</script>
```

Table.vue:

```html
<template>
  <table ref="root">
    <!-- some stuff here -->
  </table>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "vue";

export default {
  setup() {
    const root = ref(null);
    const getRef = () => root.value;

    return { root, getRef };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: but I said it wasn't related to Vue, it was a bug in *codesandbox* itself (the console component they are using)

Comment: I can really only relate to the example in OP. This doesn't work for components: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#template-refs, hence my answer.

Comment: I am the OP... and I wrote in the question the whole issue was a bug in codesandbox. the Vue code itself has no bugs

Comment: @vsync Your question title is misleading OP, `adi518` gave a solution to your question title, not to your particular problem.

Answer (score 2):

**As for the parent component**
I think the main problem is that currently on Vue 2.x you cannot put 2 direct child elements inside the template of the Vue component.
*** You actually can, but only if you'll use JSX render function instead of the `<template></template>` block.

Second, you shouldn't use `x.value` inside the template, but only use the `x` (It's handled inside the `vue-loader`). So, replace `:value="tagifyStuff.value"` to `:value="tagifyStuff"`.

**as for the cold component**
The v-model won't work on the `props.value`, because data that comes from can't be mutated.

It's not the "vue way" to pass a function in props for actions, such as "onClick".
Your component should use the $emit() method to dispatch an event, and the parent component should subscribe to this event using `@my-event="doWhatever"`

It's better to use your css from the `<style>` tag.
you can also write `<style src="@yaireo/tagify/dist/tagify.css"/>` if you insist using a separated file.

BTW, if you want to use the `Tagify` instance from the parent, why won't you just emit it?
you can write:

```
mounted() {
    this.tagify = new Tagify(this.$el, this.settings);
    this.$emit('ready', this.tagify);
}
```

and then use it in parent like that:

```
<template><my-child @ready="tagifyIsReady"/></template>
<script>
export default {
  setup() {
    let tagify;
    return: {
      tagifyIsReady: (tagifyInstance) => tagify = tagifyInstance
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<template>
    <Foo ref="myRef"/>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'
import Foo from "./components/Foo.vue"

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: { Foo },

  setup(props) {
    const myRef = ref(null)
    
    watch(myRef, newValue => {
       console.log(111,  newValue)
    })
    
    return {
      myRef
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).